Azure VM: Stoping Azure VM after creation in a CI CD pipeline task
I've been trying to solve this problem for almost two days and i need your help.
I created an Azure Pipeline on Azure DEvops that deploys a bunch of resources amongst them an Azure VM (I plan to add later more VMs), and i added an Azure Powershell task to stop the VM right after the Terraform Apply task in the YAML config file of my pipeline.
here is the two YAML tasks of Terraform Apply and Azure Powershell:

I tried the 'Install-Module Az.Compute' but my pipeline displayed this error :
Pipeline error message :

Any suggestions on this issue will be very helpful !

The error occurred as Get-AzureVM is not part of Az.Compute module. To stop VMs, make use of Get-AzVM | Stop-AzVM -Force command after running Install-Module Az.Compute -Force.

What kind of agent are you using? Self-hosted agents or Microsoft-hosted agents?

@Sridevi this worked ! I was indeed using a typo-ed command . Thank you !

@KevinLu-MSFT i'm using a Microsoft hosted agent

The reason of the error was a typo in the Az Powershell command:
Correct command
Get-AzVM | Stop-AzVM -Force

instead of :
Get-AzureVM | Stop-AzVM -Force

When in doubt always visit the Microsoft documentation : Az.Compute Module | Microsoft Learn
